# best way to find a structure in 2dimensional list python

Tags: python, 2d

I have a 2d list like this:

```
[['X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' '],
 ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X'],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

It represents a 2d map. Is there a better/more efficient way to find this structure:

```
XXX 
X X
X X
XXX
```

than this:

```
if map[y][x] == map[y][x+1] == map[y][x+2] == map[y+1][x] == map[y+1][x+2] == map[y+2][x] == map[y+2][x+2] == map[y+3][x] == map[y+3][x+1] == map[y+3][x+2] =="X" and map[y+1][x+1] == map[y+2][x+1] == " ":
    return True
else: return False
```

Comment: How about 2 `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
data = [['X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' '], ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X'], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

def check_valid(x, y, row, col):
    #check left and right column
    for i in range(row):
        #if out of range or any character is not 'X' then return wrong pattern
        if x + i >= len(data) or data[x + i][y] != 'X':
            return False
   
    #check top and bottom row
    for i in range(col):
        #same as above
        if y + i >= len(data[0]) or data[x][y + i] != 'X':
            return False

    #also we need to check the middle must all be ' '
    for i in range(1, row - 1):
       for j in range(1, col - 1):
           if data[x + row][y + col] != ' ':
               return False

    return True

for x in range(len(data)):
    for y in range(len(data[0])):
        if check_valid(x, y, 4, 3):
            print(x,y)
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 11
2 14
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain it a bit?

Comment: The first loop is to check the left column and the right column, the second loop is to check the top row and bottom row

Comment: What I'm doing here is checking for every position (x, y) from the input matrix whether the rectangle from (x, y) to (x + 3, y+ 2) contain a valid pattern

Comment: So the pattern is not valid if any character in that rectangle's bounding box is not 'X' or the rectangle is not entirely in the matrix

Comment: Edit: I just notice that the middle of the rectangle must also fill with `.` so I updated my answer, If it's not important then you can remove the last part.

Comment: But is it more efficient?

Comment: Maybe not in this case but for larger case (e.g rectangle of size 10x10) then it will be much more efficient, also less error prone